# Glass material is transparent only when object is selected

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, glass

As you can see, I would like to get similar effect in rendering as in material view mode but I'm don't know what could cause the problem. I've used Kitchen_glass material form Archipack standard library and there are two layers of glass on the door and single  layer over screen. Other side is barely visible when rendered and screen light is not visible at all (this is not actual light).

[image]

[image]

**Update**

I found out that the shadow from the glass was obscuring inside.
I've turned the "Cast" property off and now I can see through the fist glass, however I cannot see through the second glass when it's sits in the right place:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your nodes? Such problems with differences between Material and Rendered view could be caused by connecting the wrong socket (eg, a Color) to a 'Shader' socket (Green)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on the material.

Comment: I did't do anything to the material. And sorry for misinformation - the material doesn't work in blender render, not cycles. In cycles I sees something inside, although the visibility is still not great. I've attached material in picture.

Comment: You seem to be using Cycles nodes but using Blender Render as the rendering engine - this is not compatible. The original question was tagged as 'cycles' but now it's 'blender-render'. I don't know enough about Archipack - does that support Blender Render as well as Cycles?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the node editor the material have outputs for both, Blender Render and Cycles

Comment: On this page there is a link to that material library https://github.com/s-leger/archipack/wiki/Materials

Comment: The principled shader is for cycles. It won't work in blender internal.

Comment: I can see through the material in Blender Render if move the object a little bit back, but I don't want to offset the object

Comment: After more play I think the glass object is making a shadow that covers other side. How do I turn of making shadow by the glass object?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help with Blender Render, but you should avoid mixing the render engines like that - stick with one or the other or you can get unexpected results.

Answer (score -1):

You might have probably deleted the glass material. So you have to delete your object and add another one.

You can watch the following tutorial
https://youtu.be/p5q_P8WQegQ
https://youtu.be/I685JGTCpCU

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, I have the material. I'm only selecting/deselecting the object

Comment: Instead of adding more answers, please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your original answer to add aditional information.

Answer (score -1):

The in-built glass texture is very noisy in nature. You should make your own node setup as shown in the following blender guru tutorial.

https://youtu.be/KyXRBu7gn2o